# Excel and PHPExcel return different results from CUMIPMT function

Tags: php, excel, excel-formula, phpexcel, worksheet-function

I am calculating `CUMIPMT` (cumulative interest between periods) and am getting different outputs from MS Excel and [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/).

In **MS Excel**, if I enter:

```
=CUMIPMT(0.015,31.57,2000,1,31.57,0)
```

the output is `-524.94`.

Whereas using **PHPExcel** the output from the same input values is `-515.60`.

Here is my PHP code:

```
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/Calculation/Financial.php';
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel_Calculation_Financial();
$interest_paid = $objPHPExcel->CUMIPMT('0.015','31.57','2000','1','31.57','0');
```

Comment: You can always take a look at the code logic that PHPExcel has used to implement the CUMIPMT() method, which can be found in the CUMIPMT() method of PHPExcel/Calculation/Financial.php and which calls the IPMT() method in the same file, and which in turn calls the _interestAndPrincipal() method

Comment: As CUMIPMT is a static method, you don't need to instantiate  the class at all: but can simply call `PHPExcel_Calculation_Financial::CUMIPMT('0.015','31.57','2000','1','31.57','0');`

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks for your comments, I will be looking into the code and see why the result is different

Comment: @pnuts yes i have tried rounding and less demanding values, but the result is still different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Excel 2003 documentation, [Nper, start_period, end_period, and type are truncated to integers.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/cumipmt-HP005209038.aspx) - this is what the PHP version is doing. In reality, Excel (2013 at least) does not truncate, though the documentation there is slightly different: [Payment periods are numbered beginning with 1.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/cumipmt-function-HA102753070.aspx) - as for 2003 - but no mention of truncation.

Please try `31` for periods in both.

Effectively, "different Excel versions".

Comment: I will try that and get back to you :)

Comment: Thank you sooo much @pnuts, rounding the figure in excel did the trick, i am using Excel 2010, i will be checking it on different version when i see someone using an older version. Once thank thanks a lot...

Comment: Yup that's what i meant, truncating